# Function that simply returns the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

The function I'm asking for is just for convenience during programming.
Adding layers in ggplot2 with the "+" operator is great. Especially adding layers in the middle amounts to just adding another line of code.
However, if I want to try to add a layer after the last line, I have to append a "+" to the last row and if I want to remove this layer again, I also have to remove the "+" again:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,...)) +
  geom_X(...) +     # after this line, I can easily add layers
  ... +
  layer_Z(...)      # to add a layer after here, I have to modify also this line
```

I'm searching for a function `ggidentity()` which just returns the plot itself to use it as a default last line so I can easily add more lines, as in

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,...)) +
  geom_X(...) +      # after this line, I can easily add layers
  ... +
  layer_Z(...) +     # now it's easy to add layers after this line
  ggidentity()       # this doesn't change anything in the plot
```

I tried it with a simple function

```
identity <- function(x) x
```

which works well with the magrittr-package (and improves my workflow in exploratory data analysis), but not with ggplot2.

Comment: Turn `ggidentity() `  into `list()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need [geom_blank()](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_blank.html), example:

```
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_2.2.1

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_blank() # The blank geom draws nothing
```